# Unite.vim - how to open files from file browser in tabs

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, unite.vim

I'm a vim newbie and i hope you can help me:

I installed unite.vim and everything works quite fine, but I would like to add a the feature, that opening a file from the file browser (via :Unite file_rec/async) happens in a new tab, and not replacing the current file?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't installed unite.vim, but have you check the help doc? what happened, if you press `t` or `ctrl-t`?

check:

https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt#L1206

and

https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt#L2527

you can search `tabopen` in your unite.vim help doc.

Comment: t works! just make sure to escape from edit mode first.